# Javascript code for dynamic multiplication tables

Tags: javascript

Just starting with JS and stuck again. The question is to write code that will dynamically generate a timetable, allow the user to enter the number for the table they would like printed:
After trying a few different things this is where I'm at now but it's just multiplying by even numbers????

```
var y =(prompt("Please enter a number"));
var x="  ";
for (var i=0; i<=12; i++)
{
 x += y + "*" + i + "="  + (y*i) + "\n";
 i++;
 }
 alert(x);
```

Comment: You have a few syntax errors, lacking some operators between `y "x"` and `"=" (y*i)` in the line reassigning `x`.

Comment: var y =(prompt("Please enter a number"));
    var x="  ";
    for (var i=0; i<=12; i++)
    {
    x = y + "x" + i + "="  + (y*i) + "\n";
      }
    alert(x);

Ok, fixed that I think but now it's just displaying "2x12=24"

Comment: Feel free to edit your question with revised code when it offers corrections or clarification. Reading snippets within comments isn't always ideal.

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, it's all new to me, bear with me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Referring on your comment to your question, I guess you have the following.

`x = y + "x" + i +"=" (y*i) + "\n";`

Due to fact that you have this one inside your for loop `x` is overwritten anytime. So `x` is the defined value with the input `y` and the highest. `i` from the loop. And this one is printed in the alert.

Comment: Ok D3myon, I see what you mean but remember its all new to me, so how do I get the table to run through numbers 1-12 in separate lines, I know this kind of basic stuff must be so boring for ye but any help would really be appreciated?

Comment: If I get your problem correctly then try to add a line after declaring the x variable inside the loop with the following: `document.write(x);`. Please note also that you don't need to increment `i` manually.

Answer (score 0):

> it's just multiplying by even numbers????

You are incrementing 2 times `i` in the same loop !
Your code work well !

```js
var y =(prompt("Please enter a number"));
var x="  ";
for (var i=0; i<=12; i++) //<--------------
{                                       //|
 x += y + "*" + i + "="  + (y*i) + "\n";//|
 //i++;//<---------------------------------
 }
 alert(x);
```